# Problems with java swing component listener

Tags: java, swing, alignment, awt, componentlistener

I'm creating a GUI in netbeans and am attempting to make it so that the components stay properly aligned when the frame is resized, minimized, maximized, etc. I've added a component listener to do this and have added the code to both formComponentMoved and formComponentResized. This works perfectly when the form is resized or moved, the problem is it doesn't work when the form is maximized or minimized. I've attached below the code for the component listener. What am I missing here?

```
private void formComponentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                      
     jSplitPane1.setSize(new Dimension((int)(this.getWidth()*.98), (int)(this.getHeight()*.6)));
     jSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(jSplitPane1.getWidth()/2);
     jPanel1.setSize(new Dimension(jSplitPane1.getWidth()/2, jSplitPane1.getHeight()));
     jPanel2.setSize(new Dimension(jSplitPane1.getWidth()/2, jSplitPane1.getHeight())); 
     zoomToPeak.setLocation(jPanel2.getX() + 5, jPanel2.getY() + jPanel2.getHeight() + 30);
     peak.setLocation(zoomToPeak.getX() + zoomToPeak.getWidth() + 10, zoomToPeak.getY() + 1);

}                                     

private void formComponentMoved(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent evt) {                                    
    jSplitPane1.setSize(new Dimension((int)(this.getWidth()*.98), (int)(this.getHeight()*.6)));
    jSplitPane1.setDividerLocation(jSplitPane1.getWidth()/2);
    jPanel1.setSize(new Dimension(jSplitPane1.getWidth()/2, jSplitPane1.getHeight()));
    jPanel2.setSize(new Dimension(jSplitPane1.getWidth()/2, jSplitPane1.getHeight())); 
    zoomToPeak.setLocation(jPanel2.getX() + 5, jPanel2.getY() + jPanel2.getHeight() + 30);
    peak.setLocation(zoomToPeak.getX() + zoomToPeak.getWidth() + 10, zoomToPeak.getY() + 1);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: For Better help sooner,post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing layout managers.  They are the proper way to keep components aligned.

Comment: NetBeans GUI builder gives you GroupLayout by default.

Comment: Thanks, I've been messing around with layout managers but it seems like aligning components in netbeans is sometimes more trouble than it's worth

Comment: The root problem encompasses a lot of complicated things, as you've no doubt gotten a taste of trying to do it "manually" - how do things move when the window is resized?  Do they resize in addition to moving?  Less obviously, how do we make this look like other UIs so our user recognizes what it does and what it will do?  Layout Managers are constructed specifically to handle these things, often according to "principle of least astonishment", and if you're going to write good Swing UI code, then you are going to have to expend the effort to know about them.  I'm not familiar with netbeans.